# "Not only, but also" without "but"

Tags: commas, conjunctions

The racist remark is not only a careless utterance, it is also detrimental to the school's reputation.

Is it grammatically correct to use "it is also" after the comma, or do I need to use the structure "not only..., but also..."?

Comment: 'Not only - but also' comes from Latin : _non modo sed etiam_ ; there's no obligation to use it. I think your sentence is excellent, as it is, personally.